# systemd: list both active and not-found units

Tags: linux, systemd

I want to get a list of active and not-found systemd (user) units.

```
$ systemctl --user list-units --state=not-found
  UNIT                              LOAD      ACTIVE   SUB     DESCRIPTION
● server.service                    not-found active   running server.service
● pipewire-media-session.service    not-found inactive dead    pipewire-media-session.service
...
```

This lists both active and inactive units. As systemctl's manual, you can combine them as `--state=not-found,active`, but acts like an OR filter, not AND.

I guess I can just grep the previous output, but I want to ask if I can do this with just `systemctl`.

Comment: Maybe `systemctl is-enabled UNIT` is something you might want to use, check `man systemctl` for its return values. Otherwise you need to use `grep`.

Answer (score -1):

In the end, I used the dbus api to get a structured output of the available services, and filtered by not-found and active (instead of grep)